# Sitecore Social Connected - Error with login

Tags: social-connected

I have set up and configured the Sitecore Social Connected "module" (in inverted commas because it seems to be included OOTB). I have added the `Login with Facebook` rendering to a page and have set the "Application" and "Callback URL" rendering parameters on the rendering.

My page loads ok displaying the Facebook icon - I noticed the following error in the browser console window

> GET https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/XXXXXXXXXX?v=2.7.23 net::ERR_ABORTED fbevents.js:24

When I click the Facebook logo, I am redirected to

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn&redirect_uri=http://garnier-dev.com/layouts/Social/Connector/SocialLogin.ashx?type=access&scope=email,publish_actions,publish_pages,user_likes,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_location,user_religion_politics,user_relationships,user_website,user_work_history&type=web_server&state=e2fb6cff-f39e-485e-a91c-508c47cab48a
```

(nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn is the App ID which I have obscured)

Which shows the error:

> Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

I have double (and triple) checked and the hostname I am using for the site is definitely set as the "App Domains" for the App in Facebook.

Comment: Seems like it could be a Facebook specific error, rather than Sitecore - have you looked at this question on StackOverflow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain

Comment: @Kasaku it looks like it could actually have been a caching issue as it eventually seemed to "resolve itself" without me changing any settings.